# Error strip_tags() and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

In my code, booklist is a custom post type with booklink as custom field. This booklist is postobject for custom post type books

I keep getting this error

> strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string for line 11
>
> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  for line 12

```
<?php

$all= get_posts(array('post_type' => 'books', 'numberposts' => -1,));

foreach ( $all as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);

    if (!empty($post))
    {
     $booklink = array();
    
     $booklist = strip_tags(get_field('booklist')); 
               foreach ($booklist as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
                    if (!empty($post))
                        {
                        $booklink[] = strip_tags(get_field('booklink',$post));                                       
                        }
                endforeach;
                wp_reset_postdata();
echo $booklink[0]; 
            
    }
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: So what's the problem? It's pretty obvious that `get_field('booklist')` produces an object and `strip_tags` wants a string...

Comment: And `strip_tags` returns a string, or `FALSE` when there's an error, but `foreach` wants an array.

Answer (score 1):

I've added `endforeach` and removed the strip tag code for `get_field` and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're treating `$booklist` as a string here ([strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) returns a string)

```
$booklist = strip_tags(get_field('booklist'));
```

And then as an array here

```
foreach ($booklist as $post) :
```

You can't do that. `foreach` expects an array.

What you need to do (assuming `get_field` returns an array because it's clearly not returning a string) is loop through the array and run the function there

```
$booklist = get_field('booklist');
foreach ($booklist as $post) :
    $post = strip_tags($post);
```

Comment: This is not true, you can use foreach() on a string and you get one character of it in each iteration. The problem here is rather that the argument passed to `strip_tags` (`get_field('...')`) returns something else like null (not defined maybe?) in this case.

You should just check the return value of `get_field` with !is_string() and you probably wanna split that up to an array then (`explode(',',get_field('bookmarks'))`), there you have your array to iterate (I guess the field has a text value from the wordpress backend)

Comment: @Torben While it is true that you can treat a string as an array to parse it character by character, I seriously doubt that is the use case here (such a use is uncommon). The function could return null, but why would you `foreach` it then? Either way, we don't know what `get_result` actually does. The OP should enlighten us